# Unslider is not responsive with media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsiveness

on my blog I use the JavaScript plugin Unslider to present some images.
I've added media queries that will change the height of the slides. 
at first a slide's width is 75% of the viewports width.

```
.banner ul li {
    height: 75vw;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

then when the browser is over 720px, or in landscape mode I change the height to 90% of the viewports height

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px),
screen and (orientation: landscape){
   .banner ul li {
       height: 90vh;
   } 
}
```

But you will see on my website, that you either have to refresh the page, or change the slide in order to get the changes to be properly applied.

You can see what I'm talking about over here: http://78.23.161.50/posts/1

Ps. the unslider option `fluid` is set to `true`

Am I doing something wrong? Or is the Unslider plugin just not as fluid as I want it to be? 
I've also made a codepen with the structure of the website, but it's not so easy to experiment with media queries and landscape mode in a pen. Regardless, here it is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epmPmd

Comment: I noticed that the plugin sets the height for `.banner div` when the page is loaded. After that point, the plugin only sets it when image gets changed. The same problem appears on the plugins own website.

Comment: agree with @BlazeSahlzen, checked in firefox and chrome, in firefox it only shows first time but on page refresh works fine, so it's just a bug in plugin, you can report it on developer site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Would I be able to fix this?